# Oasis' song "Waiting For The Rapture" as a tribute to The Doors?

Tags: rock, pop

In Oasis’ last album, *Dig Out Your Soul*, there’s a song called *Waiting For The Rapture*.

That song has a guitar riff that is identical to the guitar riff of the The Doors song *Five To One*, and it seems a true plagiarism.

I am a huge Oasis (specially Noel Gallagher) fan and I found the demo version of that song, that sounds totally different to the release version.

Noel Gallagher always says that he likes The Doors and I guess he knows *Five To One* song, so why he changed the sound of his own song? Did he do that to make a tribute to The Doors?

Comment: Good illustration of how similar the riffs are: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXGdbr2z4Tk

Comment: It's a killer riff, but could they both be borrowing from some older source ?

Comment: [You can compare different versions of the Oasis song here ...](https://music.cliggo.com/search/Oasis+Waiting+For+The+Rapture)

Answer (score 2):

"Noel Gallagher told Q magazine October 2008 that this is, "a love song inspired by the meeting of an Angel in Ibiza.""

Bass player Andy Bell told Q magazine that he thinks its about Gallagher's girlfriend and mother of his second child, Sara MacDonald. He added: "Noel can put things in a down-to-earth way that goes right to the core."

Gallagher met MacDonald at a club on Ibiza in 2000.

Given that there have been several interviews, nothing has been mentioned about any connection with any Doors song so, in my option, it's unlikely to be a tribute song.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noel_Gallagher
https://www.songfacts.com/facts/oasis/waiting-for-the-rapture